# Simple Oracle Pivot rows to columns

Tags: oracle

We have a table that stores Name/value pairs, one record to store a Host name and another to store a port number.

Instead of returning two rows, I'd like to return one row with two columns. I could accomplish it as follows but I have several columns to return and I suspect that a PIVOT may yield simpler SQL in the end.

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD AS EMAIL_HOST
            FROM FDS_MAINT.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_DTL CCD
            WHERE CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID = 56
                AND CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'HOST'
    ) HOST,
    (
        SELECT
            CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD AS EMAIL_HOST
            FROM FDS_MAINT.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_DTL CCD
            WHERE CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID = 56
                AND CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'PORT'
    ) PORT
    FROM DUAL
```

How can I write this SQL to get the following results using a PIVOT function?

| HOST | PORT |
| --- | --- |
| testapp.silver.com | 25 |

I'm using Oracle 19.

Comment: You can also use case when  - select case when CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'HOST' then CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD end AS HOST, case when CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'PORT' then CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD end AS PORT from FDS_MAINT.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_DTL CCD WHERE CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID = 56

Comment: Thanks but that will return multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two approaches, given we are not selecting other columns with different values -

First (with pivot) -

```
select CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID,max("'HOST'") as host,
max("'PORT'") as port
from CONFGRTN_CTGRY_DTL
pivot (max (DISPL_CTGRY_CD) for CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD in ('HOST','PORT') )
group by CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID
```

Second -

```
select CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID, max(HOST) as host, max(PORT) as port 
from
(select CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID,case when CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'HOST' 
then CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD end AS HOST,
case when CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_CD = 'PORT' 
then CCD.DISPL_CTGRY_CD end AS PORT 
from CONFGRTN_CTGRY_DTL CCD 
WHERE CCD.CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID in (56,57) )
group by CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID
```

DB fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02d4cd2ea8cb633ab7c08d604384eb4d).

Comment: You forgot the WHERE CONFGRTN_CTGRY_ID = 56 in the PIVOT example in your answer but the dbFiddle had it.  Than you